# create nice tables in excel with Python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

So i have this script that outputs a pandas dataframe which i can save to a notebook. These tables however arent professional looking and i was wondering if there was a way in pandas/excel writing modules that would allow me to add column headers to my columns , a legend, merge cells, add a title, etc.

This is what i get from python as a pandas dataframe:[image]

with this script:

```
excel_df=pd.DataFrame(closeended_all_counts).T
excel_df.columns=all_columns

writer=pd.ExcelWriter('L:\OMIZ\March_2018.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')
excel_df.to_excel(writer,'Final Tables')

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Final Tables']
writer.save()
```

whereas i need this output:

[image]

any documentation or modules would be amazing!

Answer (score 2):

Since you're looking for documentation, here you go:

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_tables.html?highlight=tables